# What's the difference between MongoDB Query API and MondoDB Query Language?

Tags: api, mongodb, query, difference

So I've been trying to understand the difference between MongoDB's **Query API** and its **Query Language** but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer.

I've been reading the [MongoDB Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/query-api/) and it is written that the MongoDB Query API is "*the mechanism that you use to interact with your data*".

However, on [Devopedia](https://devopedia.org/mongodb-query-language), MQL is described as "*the interface by which clients can interact with the MongoDB server*" which sounds very similar to me.

Can someone please clarify the difference?

Comment: Both links go to the same page. The question made me think it was two different pages about two different subjects. I'm not actually sure what your question is. Can you clarify?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Hey Greg sorry about the link issue. I've fixed it now. You can check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MQL is a set of high-level syntax and grammar rules designed around interacting with the data itself, not a complete API description.

The API is MongoDB's externally-facing boundary which expects MQL as part of a payload for inbound requests;  i.e. the API also specifies a [Wire Protocol](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol) as the communication method for its consumers,  including concerns such as message transport, serialised format and response messages.